# How to plot irregularly sampled time data in animated graph, using Matplotlib or other?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, animation

I have data that is logged in irregular time steps, and I want to show it as a scrolling animation over time. For example, data A may have time points [0.001, 0.004, 0.007, 0.009, ..., 0.97], and data B may have roughly the same, plus or minus 0.02 at each point.

I want to create a scrolling animation of the data being updated over time, but only have it update a line's points/vertices after that vertex's time has passed. I cant think of a good way to have numpy say "for this line, only count data that is up this timestamp". I think if I can get that I can figure something out from the matplotlib examples, but a full solution would be nice as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe worth noting that if `a = np.array([1,3,4,8,13])`, you can filter all values below say 6 via `a[a < 6]`. Same with `>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution would be to map the data into a consistent format:

```
A = np.array([1, 1.5, 4.5, 5])
B = np.array([1, 2.5, 3.5, 5])

scroll = np.linspace(1,5,11)
A_idx = np.searchsorted(A, scroll) 
B_idx = np.searchsorted(B, scroll)

>>> scroll
array([1. , 1.4, 1.8, 2.2, 2.6, 3. , 3.4, 3.8, 4.2, 4.6, 5. ])
>>> A[A_idx]
array([1. , 1.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 5. , 5. ])
>>> B[B_idx]
array([1. , 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 5. , 5. , 5. , 5. ])
```

You might need to be careful with wether you use forward looking or backward looking values (here it is forward looking), but it will update when new data is available.